# ffmpeg scale, how to crop correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this command to encode videos

```
$transcode = FFMPEG_BINARY.' -loglevel panic -y -i "'.$files['original'].'" -vf scale='.VIDEO_SIZE_X.':'.VIDEO_SIZE_Y.' -vcodec libx264 -profile main -preset slow -r 25 -b '.VIDEO_BITRATE.' -maxrate '.VIDEO_BITRATE.' -bufsize 1000k -threads '.VIDEO_THREADS.' -acodec aac -ar 44100 -f mp4 -strict -2 '.$files['mp4'];

where: VIDEO_SIZE_X = 640 and VIDEO_SIZE_Y = 480, VIDEO_BITRATE = 900k
```

it all seems to work fine, but the problem I'm having is that the video is not resized to the desired size which is 640x480

[image: output from vlc]

^ This is the output from vlc

It looks like there's some reference to the desired size, but the video is not scaled/cropped,
what's the correct way of scaling videos in order to have the desired size? I don't mind having black stripes above and below or bands at the sides.

so, here's a bit of debugging as requested:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel panic -y -i "in.wmv" -vf scale=640:480 -vcodec libx264 -profile main -preset slow -r 25 -b 900k -maxrate 900k -bufsize 1000k -threads 8 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -f mp4 -strict -2 out.mp4
```

original video:

```
[wmv3 @ 0x13245c0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 20
Input #0, asf, from 'in.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.9600.16384
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 313
    Buffer Average  : 397
  Duration: 00:06:09.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2111 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 860x484, 2000 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 215:121, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[wmv3 @ 0x13245c0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 20
```

while the result is:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
  Duration: 00:06:08.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 975 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 645:484 DAR 215:121], 842 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 125 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

cheers

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9947/how-do-i-change-frame-size-preserving-width-using-ffmpeg may be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ffmpeg report for in.wmv shows:

```
860x484 SAR 1:1 DAR 215:121
```

The DAR (display aspect ratio) of 215:121 comes out to 1.77 (16x9). So your source is 16x9.

The ffmpeg report which you posted for out.mp4 shows:

```
640x480 SAR 645:484 DAR 215:121
```

Again, the display aspect ratio is 16x9. You may notice that the sample aspect ratio on the output is 645:484. This means that the pixels in the output are not perfect squares. Rather, they are wide rectangles. That is because 640x480 with square pixels has an aspect ratio of 4x3.

If you don't want to encode with non-square pixels, you have two options:

1) Encode to a natural 16x9 format. In this case, 854x480 would be the most natural choice.

2) Add pillarbars. You can do that by scaling to a smaller format that fits in 640x480  and then adding padding:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wmv -vf "scale=(iw*sar)*min(640/(iw*sar)\,480/ih):ih*min(640/(iw*sar)\,480/ih), pad=640:480:(640-iw*min(640/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(640/iw\,480/ih))/2" output.mp4
```

The above command will scale the input image to fill the width or height (whichever gets filled first) and then it pads the top or the sides to fill the frame. This will work with any size or format of input file. The variables (iw, sar, ih) get substituted by ffmpeg - you don't have to fill those in.  You just have to fill in the input and output file names.

Comment: I completely revised by answer based on the new information.

Comment: thank you very much, your explanation is very clear and now I understood what happened. ciao!

Comment: not sure why my edit was rejected, but the answer by Brian, while extremely correct in theory (and btw, thanks  again Brian) has a wrong example, ie: http://i.imgur.com/sIOvr0e.png

Comment: Oh, oops! Terribly sorry about that. I fixed the answer.

Comment: In your own script, you could replace all instances of 640 with VIDEO_SIZE_X and all instances of 480 with VIDEO_SIZE_Y. This would make it easier to adapt to other output formats.

Comment: That's exactly what i did :) ciao